# ionic 2 does not update page according to the changes in Firebase realtime database

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, ionic2

I am using Ionic 2 and Firebase to build an app for my project. the app should update when a new post is added to the firebase but in my case i have to move to a new page and come back to the same page to see the updates

This is my function to list the posts

```
realTimeListPosts() {
var that = this;
this.postsService.postsNode.on('value', snapshot => {
  that.userPostsLists.length = 0;
  snapshot.forEach(function (childSnapshot) {
    var data = childSnapshot.val();
    data['key'] = childSnapshot.key;
    that.userPostsLists.push(data);
  });
});
}
```

userPostsLists is an array and I use NgFor to display this array and bellow is the constructor of the provider that i have used (postService)

```
constructor(public http: Http, public preloader: Preloader) {
this.postsNode = firebase.database().ref('posts');
}
```

this is the where the realTimeListPosts() is implemented

```
constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, private loadingCtrl: LoadingController, private alertCtrl: AlertController, private viewCtrl: ViewController, public postsService: PostServices, public userServices: UserServices) {
this.userProfileLists = userServices.userProfile;
this.userId = userServices.fireAuth.currentUser;
this.realTimeListPosts();
}
```

this is the html page

```html
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar>
    <button ion-button menuToggle>
      <ion-icon name="menu"></ion-icon>
    </button>
    <ion-buttons end>
      <button ion-button icon-only (click)="addNewPostPage()">
        <ion-icon name="add"></ion-icon>
      </button>
    </ion-buttons>
    <ion-title>Home</ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>
<ion-content padding>
  <ion-card *ngFor="let post of userPostsLists">
    <ion-item>
      <ion-avatar item-left>
        <img src="{{post.photo}}">
      </ion-avatar>
      <h2>{{post.name}}</h2>
    </ion-item>
    <img src="{{post.postPhoto}}">
    <ion-item>
    <h1>{{post.title}}</h1>
    <h2>{{post.category}}</h2>
    <p>{{post.subCategory}}</p>
  </ion-item>
    <ion-card-content>
      <p>{{post.body}}</p>
    </ion-card-content>
    <ion-row>
      <ion-col>
        <button ion-button icon-left clear small (click)="goToComments(post)">
        <ion-icon name="text"></ion-icon>
        <div>Comments</div>
      </button>
      </ion-col>
    </ion-row>
  </ion-card>
</ion-content>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `NgZone` implementation as shown below with the other minor changes mentioned below.

You have to use fat arrow function as shown below.No need this static assignment `var that = this;`.Remove that and also use `let` instead of `var`.

```
import { Component, NgZone } from '@angular/core';

zone: NgZone;

realTimeListPosts() {
 this.zone = new NgZone({});
   this.postsService.postsNode.on('value', snapshot => {
     this.zone.run(() => {
      this.userPostsLists.length = 0;
       snapshot.forEach(childSnapshot =>  {
       let data = childSnapshot.val();
       data['key'] = childSnapshot.key;
       this.userPostsLists.push(data);
  });
 });
});
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help to improve my code !
I have tried your code but the problem remains the same

Comment: Where you call this method `realTimeListPosts()`?

Comment: in the constructor

Comment: You can easily avoid this issue if you use `angularfire2` with `observables`.

Comment: Can you do another try with `NgZone` as on my post above?

Comment: Thanks a lot using NgZone fixed the issue

Comment: It's my pleasure :)